# Вращение SVG с помощью transform

Tags: css, svg

Существует SVG из Material Icons

```
&::after {
        font-family: 'Material Icons Round';
        content: 'r_expand_more';
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        right: 17px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: $c-new-gray;
        transition: transform;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transition-duration: $duration-hover;
      }
```

И transform для этой SVG

```
&.isActive::after {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
```

При раскрытии выпадашки она должна вращаться вокруг своей оси на 180 градусов.

Согласно MDN мы гарантируем это с помощью `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`

[Статья MDN про transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

[Статья MDN про transform-origin в контексте именно SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform-origin)

Однако в моем случае она вращается относительно начала своих координат, какие бы значения я не использовал для `transform-origin`

Также есть потрясающая [статья](https://dockyard.com/blog/2019/11/29/an-animated-tale-of-svg-transforms), очень много рассказывающая про еще один атрибут для правильного позиционирования центра для SVG, с использованием `transform-box: fill-box;`.

Однако изменения этого параметра тоже никаких результатов не принесло.

По итогу я имею вот этот код

```
&.isActive::after {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }

      &::after {
        font-family: 'Material Icons Round';
        content: 'r_expand_more';
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        right: 17px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: $c-new-gray;
        transition: transform;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform-box: fill-box;
        transition-duration: $duration-hover;
      }
```

И в нем стрелочка выпадающего списка вращается все равно относительно (0,0), а не относительно своего центра. Возможно, проблема в том, что это SVG из библиотеки, а не хардкод. Если так, то вероятно придется отказаться от такого подхода в будущем в пользу `background: url('/svg/chevron.svg')` - здесь вообще не было проблем с анимацией.

Comment: код иконки пожалуйста добавьте в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался в вопросе. Все работает прекрасно. Большое спасибо @Alexandr_TT за ответ.

Начну с описания стека проекта. Здесь Vue 3 + Quasar.
Таким образом для добавления иконок из Material Icons Google я руководствовался документацией Quasar.

Вот [дока Quasar про использование WebFont](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/icon#webfont-usage)

Там приведена таблица с примерами использования иконок в элементах `q-icon` через атрибут `name`. Поскольку мне нужна была иконка стрелочки с закругленными краями - мне нужно по логике из этой таблицы к названию иконки из Material Icons Round (в моем случае иконка `expand_more`) добавить префикс `r_`.

Это решение работало прекрасно, иконка отображалась. Вот только есть одно НО. Не работало вращение вокруг своей оси.

Все дело в том, что правила добавления префиксов для имплементации SVG иконок актуальны ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ `q-icon`

В моем случае

```
 &::after {
    font-family: 'Material Icons Round';
    content: 'r_expand_more';
```

правило с префиксами НЕ АКТУАЛЬНО, так как не имеет отношения к Quasar. Поэтому для использования иконки с закругленными мы оставляем `font-family: 'Material Icons Round'` и просто убираем префикс. Таким образом код

```
&.isActive::after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  &::after {
    font-family: 'Material Icons Round';
    content: 'expand_more';
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: 17px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: $c-new-gray;
    transition: transform;
    transition-duration: $duration-hover;
  }
```

будет прекрасно работать. Иконка с закругленными краями и при это вращение работает корректно.

ВЫВОД: внимательно читайте документацию.

Answer (score 1):

Взял иконку [material icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons&icon.query=chevron) из Google Fonts

При таких правилах CSS (как и у вас) иконка вращается вокруг своего центра

```
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
```

```css
#chevron {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
transition:all 0.5s;
}
svg:hover #chevron {
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px">
<path id="rect" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="#d3d3d3"/>
<path id="chevron" d="M12 8l-6 6 1.41 1.41L12 10.83l4.59 4.58L18 14l-6-6z"/>
</svg>
```

Эту же иконку шеврона можно подключить с помощью

### Google-Fonts

- Подключение шрифта:

  `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Выбирать иконки по названиям можно [здесь](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons)

```css
span {
  margin: 0.5em;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
span:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg); 
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-icons">expand_less</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Вы совершенно правы, это абсолютно рабочее решение. Чуть ниже я ответил на причину проблемы в моей ситуации.